# Not getting TBB to compile test examples

Tags: block, intel, tbb, building

I am not getting TBB to work. I am following the steps in the "Getting started" document.

I am doing the following steps:

1. downloading the linux files + the sources files.
2. extracting them in 1 directory
3. calling make
4. going to tbb.../bin calling source tbbvars.sh intel64
5. going to examples/Getting_started/sub_string_finder
6. calling make

I then get the error:

```
sub_string_finder.cpp:32:30: fatal error: tbb/parallel_for.h: No such file or directory
```

I really googled a lot but can't find any related stuff.

I did also try to add some -I statement but it didnt help

I assume it is kind of a including/linking problem but I dont know how to fix.

This is all done on fedora 16 64bit. (kernel 3.1.4) // TBB version 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to install tbb-devel package.